# Installation Multiple Probe

Tags: probe, prtg

I have two HQs that need to monitor some locations from them, and dealing some problem when I install remote probes. I would be grateful if you could support me.

can I install two remote probes for each of locations to monitor?
or can I install only one remote probe for two core probes?

When I do the first scenario, the process of installation of second remote probe wants to stop first probe.There is any direction to solve this problem?
I would be appreciate if you reply me as soon as possible.

When I do the first scenario, the process of installation of second remote probe wants to stop first probe.There is any direction to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

No that isn't possible. You can only have one remote probe running on an individual server, otherwise you'd somehow have two identically named installations and services in one place.

If (from your description) you have two core servers, the probe install is directly linked to one of them, and has to report back to that specific installation. It can't report back to two of them.

The only realistic work around is to have the two PRTG Probe installs on different machines, whether physical or virtual. So for instance you could setup a VM on the machine the probe is installed on, and either run the first probe from the physical machine, and the second from within a VM, or have both of them running from their own VMs, with each probe reporting back to its respective core server. Personally I'd opt for both being in their own VM since it just makes it easier to ensure to both are setup the same.